# Why does "unhandledrejection" event not fire from the file:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

Consider the following example:

```js
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Promise executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 2000);
});

console.log("Before Promise");
var test = prom1.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data, 1);  
    return data;
  }); //skipping onReject handeler

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function() {
  console.log("unhandledrejection");  
});
```

In this case `unhandledrejection` fired, because we skipped the `onReject` handler in the `then` function. So far, everything as expected. Now let's consider another example, where I completly omit the `then` handler.

```js
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Promise executed");
    reject("Rejected");
  }, 2000);
});

console.log("Before Promise2");

//skipping onReject handeler, because we skip the whole "then" method.

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function() {
  console.log("unhandledrejection");  
});
```

Now both the scripts give same output, but if you save this code in `html` file and open **without a server(no localhost)**, e.g. as `file:///C:/Users/test/index.html` you will see that `unhandledrejection` didn't execute this time. Why is that?

P.S: I have tested on my windows 10 `Chrome Version 107.0.5304.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, `Firefox version 106.0.5 (64 bit)`, `Edge Version 107.0.1418.35 (Official build) (64-bit)` and `Opera latest version`.

P.S2: As aksed in the comments, I have added the whole html file. I had no idea that in `file://` protocol my own javascript files are considerd cross origin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, `unhandledrejection` still is fired in your second snippet.

Comment: Can't repro either. What browser are you testing this with? Tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on macOS with and without a <!DOCTYPE html> and all fired the event correctly.

Comment: @Kaiido That's strange, I have windows 10 and second script doesn't fire `unhandledrejection` in both firefox and chrome, they are latest version as well I guess 106.

Comment: @Bergi I have uploaded a video on my server showing that it can be reproduced http://sikhwarriors.xyz/promise_bug.mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your external script is considered "cross-origin" when loaded from the `file://` protocol.
This will cause its internal [**muted errors**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-script) property to be set to true.

When a classic script with its **muted errors** attribute set to true is to [track a Promise rejection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-hostpromiserejectiontracker-implementation:muted-errors), it will early exit, without firing the `unhandledrejection` event.

This is to prevent other scripts on the page to be able to read the content of this script through the event's details.

Comment: Thanks bro. This type of info should be included on MDN. How do your read all the official spec!!!

Comment: Right, I'll see to add a note in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event when I get time.